# Поиск и работа с процессами C#

Tags: c#, .net, процесс

Я получаю список всех процессов с нужным мне названием, есть ли возможность поменять название окон этих процессов, например на их ID. И менять фокус на эти окна.

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        for (int i = 0; i<localByName.Length; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(localByName[i].ProcessName.ToString() + " ID_" + localByName[i].Id.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Извлечение списка с именами и id окон процессов:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} WindowHandle {2} Window title: {3}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowHandle, process.MainWindowTitle);
    }
}
```

Подключение WinAPI функции для изменения имени окна

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);
```

Например у меня есть окно:
`Process: notepad ID: 20200 WindowHandle 1708798 Window title: Безымянный — Блокнот`
Вызываю функцию:

```
SetWindowText((IntPtr)1708798, "Небезымянный");
```

Было: "Безымянный — Блокнот"
Стало: "Небезымянный"

Можете менять как хотите прям в цикле, но учитывайте, что:

1. Не у всех процессов есть окна, но ошибки не будет, функция как раз возвращает bool в качестве ответа на успех действия.
2. У каждого процесса может быть по несколько окон, в таком случае имена окон нужно искать по-другому.
3. То единственное окно, что вы видите у процесса, может быть не главным окном.

Comment: Круто, большое спасибо. А что на счет фокуса на эти окна?  Можно-ли, к примеру,  выбирать какое окно свернуть, а какое окно сделать рабочим в данный момент, чтобы сделать в нем какое-то действие?

Comment: Чтобы управлять другими окнами - в .NET Framework, насколько мне известно, не введены все существующие WinAPI функции для работы с окнами. Смотрите WinAPI справку и ищите реализацию для C# с DllImport, или используйте вспомогательные Nuget пакеты, например https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinApi/  // minimize - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458046/c-sharp-how-to-minimize-another-application-by-a-given-process-id // focus - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898560/how-to-set-focus-to-another-window