# Как получать процесс по его имени в WinAPI? C++

Tags: c++, winapi, процесс

При попытке получить доступ к процессу я столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой. Я написал такой код:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 entry{};
entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);

Process32First(this->snapshot, &entry);
if (!process_name.compare(entry.szExeFile)) {

    return { entry };

}
```

В целом, все выглядит логично, но возникла неожиданная проблема. PROCESSENTRY32::szExeFile по документации WinAPI - это массив CHAR[260]. И он должен сравниваться с std::string при помощи метода compare(). Однако компилятор начал ругаться и я обнаружил, что на самом деле у меня это поле - это тип WCHAR[260]. А WCHAR в свою очередь псевдоним для unsigned short. Естественно unsigned short не мог сравниваться в методе compare, что и вызывало ошибку отсутствия шаблона с данным аргументом.

Напрашивается вопрос: почему у меня WinAPI не соответствует документации и что делать? Писать костыли для сравнения с unsigned short? Или же это новая версия WinAPI, которая еще не обновилась в документации и есть другой способ получения процесса по имени?

Comment: такой вопрос уже задавался и очень давно
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162064/c-processentry32

Comment: @xmikex большое спасибо. Странно, что я не наткнулся на эту тему, перерыл буквально все. Пользуясь случаем хочу задать еще один вопрос. На чем может сказаться изменение переменной UNICODE в настройках?

Comment: Совсем недавно задавал такой-же вопрос про WinAPI но для C#. Не думаю, что возникнет большая проблема интерпретировать код под C++ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1329289/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-c